# POST request to simple Django view (hosted on Heroku using gunicorn) leads to H18 Server request interrupted error

Tags: python, ios, django, heroku

I have a simple Django view I'm using to (very roughly) test making POST requests with an attached audio file. The view is simply:

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_from_audio(request):
    return HttpResponse("accepted")
```

But in my heroku logs I see:

```
2018-10-31T23:55:02.018787+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/polls/create_from_audio" host=XXX request_id=e3608c6e-8c91-440a-ade4-b854e1f72f07 fwd="174.62.90.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=163ms status=503 bytes=199 protocol=https
```

Here is the code for sending the request:

```
let url = URL(string:"...")!
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("audio/m4a", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = data
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("send error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.showLoading(message: "error sending", error: true)
            } else {
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
                NSLog("send complete, response: \(response.statusCode)")
                if let pendingMessage = self.pendingNewMessage {
                    self.conversation.messages.append(pendingMessage)
                    self.refreshUI()
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

(I realize in a production environment it would be better to upload directly to s3, but in my case I'm simply trying to test the rough speed of uploading the files with a barebones implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get this working with Django. I switched to Flask and now it's working, even with larger files of around 20MB:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("it's a post!")
        file = request.files['file']
        file.save('inprogress.m4a')
        return 'Success'
```